# Не работает Jquery выборка в SVG карте (Raphael)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Здравствуйте. Не работает такая конструкция:

```
$("[title=russia]").attr('id','example');
```

Выборка происходит из следующего элемента:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1200" height="820" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="russia" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
        <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#3899e6" d="M1039.426,586.848C1038.897,587.1129999999999,1038.502,587.376,1038.2369999999999,587.5079999999999L1038.2369999999999,587.5079999999999L1038.2369999999999,587.5079999999999C1037.7099999999998,587.376,1035.86,588.3009999999999,1035.3329999999999,588.1689999999999C1034.8039999999999,588.1689999999999,1034.74.0619999999999,683.7570000000001,475.1189999999999C683.7570000000001,476.9679999999999,682.8320000000001,478.9489999999999,681.2470000000001,480.5329999999999C688.7750000000001,481.5899999999999,706.6060000000001,480.9289999999999,712.6800000000001,477.3629999999999C712.682,477.361,712.682,477.361,712.814,477.23ZM692.343,464.55H692.2099999999999C692.078,464.946,691.814,465.475,691.6819999999999,465.87C691.947,465.475,692.21,464.947,692.343,464.55Z" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1px; stroke-linejoin: round;">
        </path>
    </a>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас нет закрывающей скобки в открывающем теге svg.

Во-вторых - xlink атрибуты находятся в XML тегах и в другом пространстве имён. Исправить пространство имён мы можем используя специальный селектор `a[*|attr=val]` который ищет по атрибуту во всех пространствах имён.

Итого пример смены id:

```
var selector = "a[*|title=russia]";

$(selector).attr('id', 'example')
```

Либо можно задать конкретное пространство имён для поиска:

```
@namespace xlink "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
var selector = "a[xlink|title=russia]";
```

Comment: Тогда как при такой выборке получить массив со значениями title ссылок?

Comment: @Sergey $("a[xlink|title]")

Comment: Есть ли какой то способ заставить такую выборку работать на IE8?