# Как добавить id к path в SVG карте на Raphael?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Встала задача сделать карту офисов на Raphael. Только проблема в том, что не могу найти решения добавления `id` к `path` в выводе карты и соответственно не могу стилизовать каждый элемент. Карту делал вот по этому мануалу

http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=32&id=952

Добавил этот код в цикл вывода карты:

```
obj.attr('id', paths[country].name);
```

Результата это не принесло.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Не работает Jquery выборка в SVG карте (Raphael)?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439626/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-jquery-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-svg-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-raphael)

Comment: В чем проблема добавить id самостоятельно руками? patch ведь добавляете руками.

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение :

```
obj.node.setAttribute("id", paths[country].name);
```